# visual studio code resource collector

Tags: resources

I'm working on a website with Visual Studio Code.
Is there a way to save only the files being used by a project into a separate folder?

Basically what I'm looking for is a tool which would scan all the local resources linked by all html files (meaning linked images, videos, files), and then it would save them all in a separate folder.
The reason why I'm asking this is because at the moment I'm testing things out, meaning I'm using image A, then image B, C and so on so forth. These images live in subfolders, so now I ended up with some images which I'm actually using in the html pages and some which I'm not. The thing is, is not simple to check which images I'm using.

You'll find the same principle in 3d applications, such as 3ds Max for instance, where, once you're done with the project, you can use a Resource Collector tool to strip out all the unused assets and save only the ones used by the project.

I've looked for an extension or a solution to this without any luck, so I guess an extension does not exist yet, but I think it would be a nice tool.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why someone downvoted my post.
Either what I'm asking is already possible, although like I said I searched and I didn't find anything, or who downvoted consider my request stupid.
Whatever the reason, I believe it would be more mature to give a proper answer, even if whoever downvoted did it for either one of the two possible reason above.
In fact:

1. The solution already exists: like I said, I didn't find it, so if someone knows the solution why not simply posting it here?
2. The solution doesn't not exist but someone thinks it's a stupid idea. Well, it is not and it would be polite and civilized to discuss it.

In the current era it became so easy to express opinions without actually doing anything, by simply pressing a button to say nothing valuable, as a "I like".
I never stop feeling amazed where the social media behavior it's taking us.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have an answer, but I completely agree with you. Why do people downvote and don't care to explain why or propose a different solution? I don't understand at all...